# Replacing a 10" solid rubber tire

Tags: tire, tricycle

I have a 50s/60 Murray Ez-Step Two Step tricycle. The solid rubber front tire is cracked almost in half and needs to be replaced. I am having an extremely difficult time finding a replacement. Here are the measurements. Tire: 9.75"OD x 7"ID x 1.375width. The rim is 7"OD x 6.5"ID x 1.375"width. Any help finding a suitable replacement would be awesome. Thank you in advance.
Mike

Comment: I don't know the best approach here necessarily, but in the penny farthing restoration world one can buy solid tire rubber by the foot to cut and glue your own. I did some googling but was unable to find the material in that width however.

Comment: Do you want authenticity?  If this bike is ridden, then a more-modern front wheel would give you a more comfortable ride and better braking.  I'm wondering how small the wheel is though - a seven inch OD is smaller than a wheelchair castor.   Check out https://www.sheldonbrown.com/rim-sizing.html   for a list of somewhat "standard" sizes.